# Overloading in PHP to keep the signature of a class same

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I have `class User` which correspond to the user table in the mySql database.
The class initialization can be done in three different ways based on what data is passed to the `class public method initialize()` by the calling function.
Initialization means saving user data in a local variable array. How the class gets this user data depends on the below mentioned conditions.

> **1.** Id is supplied to the initialize() class method, the method retrieves user data from the database based on this id and saves it in
>   a local array.
>
> **2.** Username is supplied to the initialize() class method, the method retrieves user data from the database based on this username
>   and saves it in a local array.
>
> **3.** UserData array is supplied to the initialize() class method, the method simply saves it in a local array.

**The requirement is that the calling function doesn't need to know how the class work, so for all the three ways mentioned above the class must have the same signature(?)**

Let me clarify it further with a **pseud-code**.

> **Please understand it is a pseud-code I came up with for the demonstration purpose of the functionality I am looking for within the
>   given constrain**

```
class User {

private $userData = array ();

public function __construct (){ ... }

public function initialize ( $username ) {
    //connect to database and fetch user details based on username.
    //and populate $this->userData. example : $this->userData['id'] = $this->row->id;
}

public function initialize ( $id) {
    //connect to database and fetch user details based on id.
    //and populate $this->userData. example : $this->userData['id'] = $this->row->id;
}

public function initialize ( $data) {
    //connect to database and fetch user details.
    //and save $data in $this->userData. example : $this->userData = $data;
}

}
```

Comment: From [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php):`Overloading in PHP provides means to dynamically "create" properties and methods. These dynamic entities are processed via magic methods one can establish in a class for various action types. PHP's interpretation of "overloading" is different than most object oriented languages. Overloading traditionally provides the ability to have multiple methods with the same name but different quantities and types of arguments.`

Comment: There is no way to do this on a *syntax-level*. The only way is to check the passed argument inside `initialize` (e.g. `is_string`) and react appropriately.

Comment: @Yoshi that's exactly what I thought, but the problem it poses is, that the id and username both can be of the same type i.e string.

Comment: If that's the case, you can try to to use [`is_numeric`](https://secure.php.net/manual/function.is-numeric.php) before check for string. So first check for `is_array` then `is_numeric` and the default will then be to handle it as if given a `username`. And if all fails, throw a [`InvalidArgumentException`](https://secure.php.net/manual/class.invalidargumentexception.php).

Answer (score 3):

I think you're doing it wrong.

The `User` class should have a *single responsibility*. Forcing the `User` class to also be responsible for interacting with the database seems to violate simple solid rules.

Comment: I will look into that, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You created the problem by writing strange code, write solid code and the problem goes away ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strategy partern, and mixed param for this function. I think its best way.

Private initializeWithData, initializeWithId, initializeWithName.

Comment: But how do I differentiate between data of the same type ? For example both id and username can be of the same type i.e string. And there can be possibly more same type arguments passed to the function.

Comment: Use call_user_func_array to pass other arguments. You can't differinate string id from string, only if try found first as id.